# Password protected site dialog

Tags: html, dialog, passwords

Over the course of the last week I have been attempting to make a web-based application for work. I have successfully managed to create and implement everything to a point that it is functional.

I'm not sure if this last piece of the project I'm embarking on is even a possibility, but I also don't seem to know how to search for it, if it is.

The URL that is bookmarked on the work 'dashboard' (iPod) is password protected. Currently, after the splash screen, it presents the log in screen with the following fields displayed:

> "Authentication Required
>
> "www.adsomneum.com"
>
> "user name"
>
> "password"

What I'm wondering is if it is possible to remove, replace, or hide the line that reads "www.adsomneum.com" as this is my private website, and others at my work place have no need for information regarding it.

I'm using `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` as my means for password protection.

Comment: `make a web-based "app" for work`...`this is my private website, and others at my work place have no need for information regarding it.` - surely these are contradictory?

Comment: Fair observation... what I mean is.. I've created the shortcut to the part of the page that concerns work, the rest of it (though I don't care if they see, I was just trying to give it a more professional look) doesn't really benefit them in the work place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally there's an option of using AuthName in the .htaccess to set a name for the protected area (eg: "Admin Console" or "Member's Area").

BUT I'm fairly certain (and my quick testing just now confirms it) that iOS will only ever show the domain. I'm pretty sure this is for security reasons so there's no way around it.

Comment: That's what I figured, I just wasn't sure.

Alternatively, even after changing the "AuthName," pulling the webpage up in a web browser on my PC, it still shows the site name in the username/password dialog box.  Maybe there is just no way to bypass it at all using this login method.

Answer (score 0):

You say you are using .htaccess and .htpasswd, so I'm guessing that means you are using auth-basic. In the config variables of your .htaccess file you should have one called AuthName - I *think* that the browser is displaying that. Do you have www.adsomneum.com as your AuthName? If so just change it to "private area" or "xyz tool" or something similar.

Comment: I thought the same thing, and changed it to the following code:
AuthType Basic
AuthName "This app for service management only"  
AuthUserFile [Url-to-password-file]
require valid-user

No luck